# Can the grease pencil draw on a plane axis in the perspective view?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]I would like to draw on an axis plane while in the 3D perspective view (not front/side views, ect.) The only way I've found to do this is with an object plane (which MUST be visible... no wireframe view). I would like to do it on an adjustable invisible plane which can be quickly targeted.

My desire is to have the ultimate concepting tool for level design, by drawing on an invisible plane in the x, y, and z. I lack the programming skill to make this tool but I'm studying.

What I'm hoping is that there's already a way or addon to do this.[![Level concepting in 3D with grease pencil][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Answered your question yourself.

What you need to do is to add a plane and align it to view  (From the adding option),Using local transform orientation,move the plane in he local z axis to the level you want to draw in.

Now all you have to do is to put your 3D cursor into the surface of the plane just by clicking anywhere in the plane with the <kbd>LMB</kbd> .

So suppose I have this object and I want to draw on he shades face:

[image: Example]

Now add the plane and pt the 3d cursor on it :

[image: Example 1]

And you are ready to paint,Assuming your stroke placement is set to Cursor,you are good.And you can just delete h plane it is no needed.

[image: Face]

Comment: I was thing of something much, much faster. I want to draw flat on an axis and move that axis in just a few seconds (on all 3 axis) to sketch structurally in 3D. (As an addon, preferably by moving an axis plane with my tablet pen on the fly). I may have to arrive at a point where I must build the tool myself.Thank you very much for your method though :)

Comment: I"ve changed my screenshot. I found a hack way to do this by creating 3 planes and turning on the snapping tools. Then I can move it around and draw as needed :)  This will work for now until I can build a more versatile tool.